# How do I use a minimization function in scipy with constraints

Tags: python, optimization, numpy, scipy

I need some help regarding optimisation functions in python(scipy)
the problem is optimizing `f(x)` where `x=[a,b,c...n]`. the constraints are that values of a,b etc should be between 0 and 1, and `sum(x)==1`. The scipy.optimise.minimize function seems best as it requires no differential. How do I pass the arguments?

Creating an ndarray using permutation is too long. My present code as below:-

```
import itertools as iter
all=iter.permutations([0.0,.1,.2,.3,.4,.5,.6,.7,.8,.9,1.0],6) if sum==1
all_legal=[]
for i in all:
if np.sum(i)==1:
    #print np.sum(i)
    all_legal.append(i)
print len(all_legal)
lmax=0
sharpeMax=0
for i in all_legal:
    if sharpeMax<getSharpe(i):
        sharpeMax=getSharpe(i)
        lmax=i
```

Comment: Aside: [`iter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter) is the name of a built-in function, so it's not a good abbreviation for `itertools`.

Comment: It's not immediately clear what you want to optimize. Can you describe the problem in a bit more detail?

Comment: I heavily recommend reading the chapter about [Optimization](http://scipy-lectures.github.io/advanced/mathematical_optimization/) in the Scipy lectures. Well worth a read.

Answer (score 34):

You can do a constrained optimization with `COBYLA` or `SLSQP` as it says in the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html).

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

start_pos = np.ones(6)*(1/6.) #or whatever

#Says one minus the sum of all variables must be zero
cons = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x:  1 - sum(x)})

#Required to have non negative values
bnds = tuple((0,1) for x in start_pos)
```

Combine these into the minimization function.

```
res = minimize(getSharpe, start_pos, method='SLSQP', bounds=bnds ,constraints=cons)
```

Comment: `sum(k for k in x)` is also known as `sum(x)`. :)

Comment: @Dougal Years later when I get a notification about this answer I still facepalm over this.

Answer (score 7):

Check `.minimize` docstring:

```
scipy.optimize.minimize(fun, x0, args=(), method='BFGS', jac=None, hess=None, hessp=None, \
              bounds=None, constraints=(), tol=None, callback=None, options=None)
```

What matters the most in your case will be the `bounds`. When you want to constrain your parameter in [0,1] (or (0,1)?) You need to define it for each variable, such as:

```
bounds=((0,1), (0,1).....)
```

Now, the other part, `sum(x)==1`. There may be more elegant ways to do it, but consider this: instead of minimizing `f(x)`, you minimize `h=lambda x: f(x)+g(x)`, a new function essential `f(x)+g(x)` where `g(x)` is a function reaches it minimum when `sum(x)=1`. Such as `g=lambda x: (sum(x)-1)**2`.

The minimum of `h(x)` is reached when both `f(x)` and `g(x)` are at their minimum. Sort of a case of Lagrange multiplier method http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier

Answer (score 1):

Another way of weighting variables where the sum of the weights is constrained to equal 1, is to use `minimize` with no constraints, initialize with near-zero values but use a `softmax` in the scoring function.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import softmax
from scipy.optimize import minimize

initial_weights = np.random.normal(scale=0.01, size=(n_weights))

def getSharpe(x):
    weights = softmax(x)
    ....
    # Sharpe ratio calculation
    ....
    return -score


# Any optimization method can now be used - we are not limited to SLSQP
res = minimize(getSharpe, initial_weights, method='L-BFGS-B')
```

Since any optimizer can be used, parallel algorithms can be used for a speed up e.g. [optimparallel](https://github.com/florafauna/optimParallel-python)

Comment: I'm intrigued! So I've gone and asked [What problems does softmax() solve and when should I think of using it - in simple terms](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/42148/17869) in SciComp SE.