# Minimise multiple parameters whilst keeping the same ratios between the parameters

Tags: python, scipy

I have a particular function which calculates average cost of electricity ($/MWh) over the lifetime of a power plant.

An example function looks like this

```
def calc(a,b,c):
     res = 65*a+74*b+12*c
     return res
```

Where `a` `b` and `c` are cost parameters, such as operating expenditure, construction cost and insurance.

I could vary `a` `b` and `c` in an infinite number of ways, but I would like to keep the ratios the same as an example data point I have, with a lower result for average cost of electricity.

For example
When `a=1`, `b=2` and `c=3`, `res = 249`.

However, I would like to find out the optimal values, which keeps the same original ratios, for `a` `b` and `c` when `res=600`

I have tried to figure out a way to do this using scipy.optimize, but with some difficulty.

I'm not sure how I would program in the ratios for the constraints.

Many thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use a minimization function in scipy with constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18767657/how-do-i-use-a-minimization-function-in-scipy-with-constraints)

Comment: Thank you for this. However, I was wondering how to define the constraints of ratios for lots of different parameters. I have 7 parameters in my example. Thanks.

Comment: Which ratios exactly do you want to be equal? If you have 3 numbers, there are 3 ratios you will have to satisfy - in the end, you can only change your numbers by an overall multiplicative factor (that is the same for every parameter)

Comment: Thank you for your comment @rammelmueller. Please see my response to Bill M.'s answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to come to a solution which helped my particular use-case, even though it was pointed out that there was a simpler solution for this particular example.

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np

a = 1
b = 2
c = 3

def calc(x):
    res = 65*x[0]+74*x[1]+12*x[2]
    return res

cons = [{'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: x[0]/x[1]-a/b},
        {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: x[1]/x[2]-b/c},
        {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: calc(x)-600}]

start_pos = np.ones(3)*(1/6.)

print(minimize(calc, x0=start_pos, constraints=cons))
```

The constraints keep the same ratios, and set the result of calc to equal 600.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have two sets of values, (a_old, b_old, c_old) and (a_new, b_new, c_new).  If you want their respective ratios to be the same (e.g., a_old:c_old is the same as a_new:c_new, and c_old:b_old is the same as c_new:b_new, and so on), then that's the same as saying there exists some constant k such that a_new = k*a_old, b_new = k*b_old, and c_new = k*c_old.

In your example, 65*a_old + 74*b_old + 12*c_old = 249.  If you multiply both sides of this equation by k, you get 
65(k*a_old) + 74(k*b_old) + 12(k*c_old) = 249*k.  This is the same as '65(a_new) + 74(b_new) + 12(c_new) = 249k'.

You want 249*k to be equal to 600.  Therefore, k = 600/249 = about 2.4096.  You can then use this k value along with a_old, b_old, c_old to find the values of a_new, b_new, c_new.  Remember the new values are just k times the old values.

Here's a function that returns the set of scaled parameter values:

```
def optimize(a,b,c, opt_res):
    res = 65 * a + 74 * b + 12 * c
    k = opt_res/res
    new_vals = [parameter * k for parameter in [a,b,c]]
    return new_vals

print(optimize(1,2,3,600.0))

## output: [2.4096385542168677, 4.819277108433735, 7.2289156626506035]
```

Note I used "600.0", not "600".  This forces Python to use floats instead of doing everything with truncated integers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry, I should have made more clear, in this example problem this would be the best solution, but in my actual project I need to use constraints as the calculations to calculate a, b and c are rather complicated.

Comment: You're welcome, but I'm sorry I don't quite understand what you need here. Maybe you can show where `scipy.optimize()` is giving you errors.

Comment: it really does not matter, how many parameters you want to have - if the ratios are the same, you'll always have this issue. without knowing the exact form and constraints, it will be challenging to do anything here.

Answer (score 1):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20075714/scipy-minimize-with-constraints) answer, you can specify the constraints like this:

```
cons = [{'type':'eq', 'fun': con1},
        {'type':'eq', 'fun': con2}]
```

and use the minimize function like this:

```
scipy.optimize.minimize(func, x0, constraints=cons)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This helped.

Comment: I am glad it helped. Good luck in your projects! If you can, mark it as the answer